# How to Forward $scope from Controller to Controller AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am  New to Angular Js.

Is It Possible to Forward Scope of the **RestaurantController** to  **MenuController** Code as Follows

Example :-

```
angular.module('restaurants').controller('RestaurantController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
       $scope.restaurantid="435scvcxvbrcvbnvn";

    }

]);
```

And i assigned  restaurant id as  New scope  in Menu Controller  as Follows

```
angular.module('menus').controller('MenuController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
            $scope.currentrestaurantid= $scope.restaurantid;
          alert($scope.currentrestaurantid); // showing Null
     }

]);
```

The Restaurant Id is not Persisted .. Honestly i feel that some thing is Missing .

**How to Get the Id From Restaurant controller to Menu Controller  ?**

Comment: You should use an Angular service or factory to store common data instead of trying to "subclass" controller scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inheritance

```
angular.module('restaurants', []);
angular.module('menus', ['restaurants']);

angular.module('restaurants').controller('RestaurantController', function($scope) {
       $scope.restaurantid="435scvcxvbrcvbnvn";
});

angular.module('menus').controller('MenuController', ['$scope','$controller',
    function($scope, $controller) {
        $controller('RestaurantController', {$scope: $scope});
            $scope.currentrestaurantid= $scope.restaurantid;
     }

]);
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/14420/)

Answer (score 1):

I propose use the rootScope to do that.

Use the $broadcast to notify the other controller the change on the firsts controller scope.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("restIDUpdated", {
     restaurant: $scope.restaurantid
});
```

Use the $on to receive the notification in the second controller about the event that happend in the first controller.

```
$scope.$on("restIDUpdated", function (event, args) {
    $scope.restaurant = args.restaurant;
});
```

There is an example of this [here](https://github.com/koitoer/Angular-sandbox/blob/develop/controller-communication-ang)

Try something like this.

```
angular.module('restaurants').controller('RestaurantController', function($scope) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast("restIDUpdated", {
            restaurantid: 435scvcxvbrcvbnvn
     });
});

angular.module('menus').controller('MenuController', ['$scope','$controller',
function($scope, $controller) {
    $controller('RestaurantController', {$scope: $scope});

$scope.$on("restIDUpdated", function (event, args) {
                    $scope.currentrestaurantid= args.restaurantid;
                });
 }

]);
```

But to be honest I am not sure if this mechanism works with two different angular apps, I know using the same module it works but not sure what is going to happen using two different modules, but take a look at the [API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Answer (score 1):

A pattern I commonly use is to create an angular service and inject it into controllers I want to share data with.  something like this...

```
angular.module('restaurants', []);
angular.module('menus', ['restaurants']);

angular.module('restaurants').service('RestaurantService', function() {
    this.restaurantid = "435scvcxvbrcvbnvn";                                    
});

angular.module('restaurants').controller('RestaurantController', function($scope, RestaurantService) {
       $scope.restaurantid = RestaurantService.restaurantid;
});

angular.module('menus').controller('MenuController', function($scope, $controller, RestaurantService) {
       $scope.currentrestaurantid = RestaurantService.restaurantid;
});
```

Comment: Dude ..You Know How to Write the Dynamic Value in to service instead of Static ?

Answer (score 1):

As said here, injectable service as generic way for your situation.
But I'd like to point more pretty way, using markup and `controller as` ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)) expression.

For example you have following controller:

```
.controller('RestaurantController', function($scope) {
       $scope.restaurantid="435scvcxvbrcvbnvn";
 })
```

and you can bind it to variable in the scope:

```
<div ng-controller="RestaurantController as restaurant">
    <div ng-controller="MenuControllerOrAnyOther">
        restaurant id = {{restaurant.restaurantid}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Remarks**

This approach would be nicer if you need `restaurantid` ONLY in markup, e.g.

```
<button ng-click="select(restaurant.restaurantid)">
```

This looks ugly, if you want to use `restaurantid` in js code (you should use injectable services then):

```
var restaurantid = $scope.$eval('restaurant.restaurantid');
```